# Processing live feed of logs from web server using Hadoop

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

I want to process the logs from my web server as it comes in using Hadoop (Amazon Elastic mapreduce). I googled for help but nothing useful. I would like to know if this can be done or is there any alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is usually used in an offline manner. So I would rather process the logs periodically.

In a project I was involved with previously, we made our servers produce log files that were rotated hourly (every hour at x:00). We had a script that ran hourly (every hour at x:30) uploaded the files into HDFS (those that weren't already there). Then you can run jobs as often as you like in Hadoop to process these files.

I am sure there are better real-time alternatives too.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is not used for live real time processing. But it can be used to process logs on hourly basis may be one hour behind which is near real time. I wonder what is the need of processing logs as it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is to use Flume as a log collector and store them in S3 for batch processing:

http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/02/distributed-flume-setup-with-an-s3-sink/

Answer (score 0):

If you want true real-time processing, you might want to look at [Twitter's Storm](http://storm-project.net/), which is open-source and hosted on GitHub. [Tutorial here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Tutorial).

It looks like it is being [used in production](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Powered-By) at large companies.

On that note, I don't use Storm myself, and actually do something similar to what has been in mentioned in the question and responses:

1. Log events using Apache (using rotatelogs for changing log files every 15/30 minutes)
2. Upload them every so often to S3
3. Add a new step to an existing Hadoop cluster (on Amazon EMR)

With Hadoop, you can get close to real-time by running the batch processing often on a cluster and just adding a new job, but not true real-time. For that you need Storm or something similar.